# Double-click on a node to fade out all but its immediate neighbours. Double-click to bring them back again

Tags: d3.js

I am using the below code for the iamges and mouseover text. And now i have added the code for double click on a node to fade out all but it is not working and also link color is not changing. Can anyone help on this

```
       var width = 960,
       height = 500

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height);

     var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.1)
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

      var voronoi = d3.geom.voronoi()
     .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
     .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
     .clipExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]]);

     d3.json("miserables1.json", function(error, json) {
     if (error) throw error;

     force
      .nodes(json.nodes)
      .links(json.links)
      .start();

     var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
     .data(json.links)
     .enter().append("line")
     .attr("class", "link", "fill:red; stroke:red;");

     var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(json.nodes)
     .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);
    node.append("svg:image")
   .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.imagen })
   .on('dblclick', connectedNodes);
    var circle = node.append("circle")
   .attr("r", 4.5);

   var label = node.append("text")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

   var cell = node.append("path")
  .attr("class", "cell");

   force.on("tick", function() {
   cell
    .data(voronoi(json.nodes))
    .attr("d", function(d) { return d.length ? "M" + d.join("L") : null;    });

   link
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    circle
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

    label
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x + 8; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });
   });
   });


     var toggle = 0;

     var linkedByIndex = {};
     for (i = 0; i < graph.nodes.length; i++) {
     linkedByIndex[i + "," + i] = 1;
     };
     graph.links.forEach(function (d) {
     linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
     });

    function neighboring(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
    }
    function connectedNodes() {
    if (toggle == 0) {
    //Reduce the opacity of all but the neighbouring nodes
    d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
    node.style("opacity", function (o) {
        return neighboring(d, o) | neighboring(o, d) ? 1 : 0.1;
    });
    link.style("opacity", function (o) {
        return d.index==o.source.index | d.index==o.target.index ? 1 : 0.1;
    });

    toggle = 1;
    } else {

    node.style("opacity", 1);
    link.style("opacity", 1);
    toggle = 0;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on `it is not working`: what behaviour is required, what have you observed?

Comment: When i double click the node then the linked nodes only should appear. remaining needs to be disappear. And again on double click they have to appear again

Comment: Can anyone help me on this

Comment: `When [I] double click […] linked nodes only should appear. remaining […] disappear` - looks like required behaviour: please edit into your question - and don't forget do describe observed behaviour, too. (Just try to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), no need to plead for answers/help.)

Comment: This is about fading out nodes and links that aren't connected to the node you've doubleclicked on. And observed behavior is when i am double clicking on the node no change in the behavior.